# What is the best way to register WPF ViewModels against Views in an AutoFac container?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, autofac

I haven't been able to find guidance on registering views and viewModels with AutoFac. My goal is to have it so when a view is created (by the system or through a view creation service), the viewModel specified is resolved by AutoFac and applied to the view's DataContext.

Here's the somewhat hacky solution I have so far:

```
builder.Register(t => new CatView() { DataContext = t.Resolve<CatListViewModel>() });
```

This works in that the viewModel is instantiated and applied as the DataContext when the view is created. **But** the viewModel's Dispose() method won't be called until the scope's lifetime ends (when the application is closed?), which could lead to memory leaks since a new viewModel is created every time the view is opened.

I believe other DI frameworks such as Ninject and Prism do have view/viewModel specific registration calls, which makes me think I'm doing something wrong. Please let me know of a better approach to view/viewModel registration with AutoFac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it all back-to-front. One of the main reasons for doing MVVM is to facilitate unit-testing i.e. your application should be able to run without creating any views at all!

With that in mind, the usual way of mapping the two in WPF is via DataTemplates, and your choice of DI framework shouldn't make any difference. Basically you do this:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MyViewModelType">
    <views:MyViewControl />
</DataTemplate>
```

Now anything that uses a ContentPresenter (ListBoxes etc) will populate itself with that view whenever its content bound to the corresponding view model. You can also do it explicitly like this:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding SomeViewModelProperty}" />
```

If you're adament about doing things the hard way then take a look at Jonathan Yates' "Adventures in Xamarin Forms" tutorials, the pages themselves are unfortunately long gone but you can still read it all [on the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20150407065012/http://adventuresinxamarinforms.com/2014/11/21/creating-a-xamarin-forms-app-part-6-view-model-first-navigation). It's all Xamarin of course, but very easy to port to WPF. I did use it on a few projects, but eventually replaced it all with a custom DataTypeSelector that just implemented the WPF-style DataTemplates.

Comment: Mark, thanks for the answer. I was worried that the data templating option might not be "true MVVM" since the view would be coupled to the viewModel type. But on reflection, I don't think that's actually as big of a deal since the two objects are coupled through the data bindings anyway. I'll look more into this option.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think you can escape the fact that there's always an implicit interface coupling through bindings anyway. Xamarin took this a step further with the introduction of compiled bindings which at least adds an additional layer of type-safety so that you catch things at compile-time rather than run-time.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question about ViewModel/View lifetimes. One of the companies I worked for used a ViewModel first approach which you might like.

They called it "Activity".

```
public interface IActivity<T>
{
    Task<T> Result { get; }
}

public class RegistrationActivity : IActivity<Person>
{
    private TaskCompletionSource _tcs;
    public Task<Person> Result => _tcs.Task;

    public string Name {get;set;}

    public ICommand Ok => new RelayCommand(() => _tcs.SetResult(new Person(Name)));
    public ICommand Cancel => new RelayCommand(() => _tcs.SetCancelled());

}

public class RegistrationWindow : Window
{
    public RegistrationWindow(RegistrationActivity viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponents();
        DataContext = viewModel;
        viewModel.Task.ContinueWith(() => Close());
    }   
}

builder.Register<RegistrationWindow>();
```

Comment: Hi Aron, thanks for the answer. This is definitely an interesting, novel approach. I did see some guidance that recommended the viewModel be injected into the view's constructor, as part of your solution shows. It makes sense from a traditional DI perspective. However, I was worried that that wouldn't be true MVVM/WPF since the codebehind isn't "pure." Maybe I'm taking that rule too seriously.

Comment: Actually I was only putting this code together to show a minimal demo of the concepts. I would perhaps use an MVVM framework to do a ViewModel first approach, such as Prism. That way the VMs only create VMs, whilst Prism auto constructs a `IViewFor<TViewModel>` and displays it.